# getting difference of 2 time since epoch in days

Tags: python

I was wondering for a short way to do this:

Lets say I have 2 time since epoch: `1418647594` and `1418177737`; how would I get the difference of the 2 **in days**? I know there are similar questions but they involve installing modules. This one is slightly different!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using the `datetime` module?

Comment: Yes, I have that installed

Comment: Take the diff and divide by 86400 ?

Comment: Okay, so make two `datetime` objects and subtract them. You'll get a `timedelta` object that you can ask for in days.

Comment: woah, that really is fast, that is a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use datetime:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> diff = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1418647594) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1418177737)
>>> diff
datetime.timedelta(5, 37857)
>>> diff.days
5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tStart = 1418177737
tStop = 1418647594
tElapsed = tStop - tStart
diffSeconds = tElapsed / 1000 % 60
diffMinutes = tElapsed / (60 * 1000) % 60
diffHours = tElapsed / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24
diffDays = tElapsed / (24 * 60 * 60 * 100)
```